# Cordova inAppBrowser IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm facing a problem in Cordova on the InAppBrowser in IOS, when i open the InAppBrowser in landscape mode, and use the "Done" button to return to my app again is shows a blank screen.
Cordova version: 6.4.0
InAppBrowser version: 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug with your working envorments : 
Try to use

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

  ref.addEventListener('exit', myCallback);

function myCallback(){
location.reload();
}
```

in myCallback function ,it reloads the page.

Comment: What does location refer to?

Comment: @RikvanEck the page in your "app" which inappBrowser started from .

Comment: It doesn't help to reload.

Answer (score 0):

`cordova-plugin-statusbar` & `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` apparently don't play nice together. You can either delete `cordova-plugin-statusbar` if you're not using it (deleting it results in a weird background color on the status bar for Android), or, you can try the workaround below:

```
openUrl(url) {
  let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options);

  ref.addEventListener('exit', () => {
    StatusBar.hide();

    setTimeout( () => {
      StatusBar.show();
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```